# Using AJAX to submit to same page and show content if $_GET['submit'] is set

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building an app which lists a number of files. There is a button at the bottom of the page that says "View older", which I want to use to load in a list of older files. At the moment it works fine when clicking the button; it reloads the page, and as submit has been set, shows the older. However, I'd rather do this without it loading again.

How would I use AJAX to do this? Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Older" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 listholder">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <?php
            if( isset($_GET['submit']) ){ 
                $old_directory = 'oldeshots';
                $scanned_old = array_diff(scandir($old_directory), array('..', '.'));

                foreach ($scanned_old as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<li class="list-group-item">';
                    echo "<a href='$value?old=true'>$value</a>";
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            } ?>
        </ul>                    
    </div>

</div>
```

AJAX Code so far (there isn't much to it at the moment!):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$.ajax( {
      url:'index.php',
      data: , //What goes here?
      success:function(data) {
      //What goes here?
      }
    });

});
```

I have played around with jQuery .ajax() but I don't see how this can set the $_GET variables. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When using jQuery.ajax() you may set the parameter 'data' in the call to specify any key/value pairs you need to send with your request.

Comment: Show us the AJAX code

Comment: So that currently refreshes the page? In order for the PHP (if it's in the same file) to pick up the `$_GET['submit']` parameter, it would have the have the page refresh. (afaik) Ajax could load the content in, but the PHP would need to be in an external file.

Comment: So if you want to make this PHP code fit an ajax call add all values you want sent to the PHP scrpt to `data: {submit: "yes"},` for example. GET is the default for a `jQuery.ajax` call or you can add `method: POST,` to the param list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getfiles.php**:

```
<?php 
$old_directory = 'oldeshots';
$scanned_old = array_diff(scandir($old_directory), array('..', '.'));
echo json_encode($scanned_old);
```

**ajax code**:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'getfiles.php',
        data: {myvar1: 'value', myvar2: 'value2'}, // You don't need this in this case. But this is how you use it.
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,value){
                $(".list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item"><a href="'+ value +'?old=true">'+value+'</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your php file**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Older" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 listholder">
        <ul class="list-group">

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**ajax call**

$('#submit').on('click', function(e){

```
e.preventDefault();
var data = 'oldeshots';

$.ajax( {
          type : 'GET',
          url:'getdata.php',
          data: data,
          success:function(data) {
                $('ul.list-group').html(data);
          }
});
```

});

**getdata.php**

```
 <?php 
   if( isset($_GET['submit']) ){ 

       $old_directory = $_GET['data'];
       $scanned_old = array_diff(scandir($old_directory),     array('..', '.'));
       foreach ($scanned_old as $key => $value) {
           echo '<li class="list-group-item">';
           echo "<a href='$value?old=true'>$value</a>";
           echo '</li>';
       }
   }
?>
```